# Problem opening .sh file

Tags: installation, 12.10

I'm trying to install Torchlight from the Humble Indie Bundle 6. The installation file is an sh file.
When I try to run the sh file I get this output.

```
[ user@pc:~/Desktop$ sudo sh ./Torchlight-2012-09-26.sh
[sudo] password for user:
Current temporary directory (usually /tmp by default) does not seem to be executable!      
Please specify an alternative path by using the --target option.]
```

How do make the tmp dir executable or specify an alternate path?

I'm running ubuntu 12.10

Comment: What command is being executed within the shell script when this error is reported?

Comment: are you sure that your script is to be executed by dash (sh) and not by bash?

Comment: I'm new to linux and I don't know what bash is.

Comment: Since `dash` is the default shell on Ubuntu *for running scripts* (while `bash` is the default *interactive shell*), it does make sense that the script should be run with `dash` instead of `bash`. (For some time now, `sh` has been a symlink to `dash`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/tmp` folder sounds like it is a separate filesystem mounted with the `noexec` option.

This is an intentional security measure to prevent the execution of programs written to the `/tmp` folder, but it's not the default setup of Ubuntu.

The script suggests a workaround - use the `--target` option to specify a different folder.

e.g.

```
mkdir ~/tmp # Make a temp folder in your home folder
sudo sh ./Torchlight-2012-09-26.sh --target ~/tmp # Tell the installer to use it
rm -rf ~/tmp # remove it afterwards
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to enter the following in to Terminal:

```
sudo sh ./Torchlight-2012-09-26.sh --target $PWD
```

or

```
sudo sh ./Torchlight-2012-09-26.sh --target /home/user/
```

Answer (score -1):

run this in terminal :

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp /var/tmp
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  When answering a question - please expand an answer explaining what you are about to say, possible consequences, what the commands will do, rollback etc.  Thanks.